# jquery selector display and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adblock

So I have two div's and in each one of them there's a img, first div image will be an ad, provided by a ad manager, when chromes adblocker blocks this ad div I want the second div to display in that same area. below is that code I've written but this doesn't seems to work I guess, pls help me fix this?

html markup

```
<div class="iw-300x250-right ">
    <img class="iw-300x250-img" alt="" border="0" src="http://addmanagerlink/banners/63-1-1444562919.png" width="300" height="250">
    <div class="iw-boxy-placeholder">
        <img src="imagelink" width="300" height="250">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.iw-boxy-placeholder img {
    display: none;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('img.iw-300x250-img').css('display') == 'none') 
        {
        $('.iw-boxy-placeholder img').css('display') == 'block !important')
    });
    })
```

Comment: thanks for your help @tushar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntactical issues in your code, apart from that I think you might need a better handler as the blocker can remove the element or it can run after the dom ready so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fn = function () {
        if (!$('img.iw-300x250-img').length || $('img.iw-300x250-img').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.iw-boxy-placeholder img').show();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    var timer = setInterval(fn, 1000);
    fn();
})
```

Comment: @A.Wolff what was I thinking?

Comment: hi @Arun, when I resize the browser the .iw-boxy-placeholder img shows up, and stays untile I refresh the page again. so I modified the code but still it doesn't hide the placehoder when the browser is being manually resized.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        var fn = function() {
            if (!$('iw-300x250-right-768').length || $('iw-300x250-right-768').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.iw-boxy-placeholder-768 img').show();
                clearTimeout(fn, 1000);
            }
            else{
                $('.iw-boxy-placeholder-768 img').hide();
            }
        }
        var timer = setInterval(fn);
        fn();
    })
});

this is how i modifed it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('img.iw-300x250-img').is(":hidden")) 
        {
        $('.iw-boxy-placeholder img').show();
    });
    })
```

check if first div image is hidden, if yes show second div image.